# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns wrong path

Tags: java, android, filesystems, storage

I have the next situation: Android 4.1, device doesn't have an external SD card. The following code:

```
File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() );
```

returns 
**/storage/sdcard0**

Then I try create a file there and get the error 
**java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**.
 My application has necessary lines in its manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In order to resolve this issue I started adb and got file list, this is the  fragment:

**lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-01 03:12 sdcard -> /storage/sdcard0**
**lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-01 03:12 sdcard2 -> /storage/sdcard1**
**d--xr-xr-x system   sdcard_r          2000-01-01 03:12 storage**

And I don't have permissions to access to **/storage/sdcard0** but I can access to **/storage/sdcard1** there are dirs:
ABBYY
Alarms
Android
Books
CheetahBrowser
DCIM
Download
SlideIT
etc.

It seems that **getExternalStorageDirectory()** mere works bad. And it seems weird owing to other applications that could write files in a correct place. What I do wrong?

**Update:**
getExternalStorageState() returns "removed"

I ignored a result of getExternalStorageDirectory() and set a path manually to "/storage/sdcard1" then everything works good, I can create dirs and files.

Comment: check the storage with getExternalStorageState() if it is mounted or not...

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem, it was an exotic one. The device at the beginning had had an external SD card and this card was the "default memory". Then the SD card had been removed but the default memory hadn't been switched to the internal "built-in" storage. As a result the system has been returning an incorrect path to storage until I have corrected the "default memory" setting and the problem disappeared.

Comment: thanks for your finding and answer, i am relying on getExternalStorageDirectory() to create a folder in user's "internal phone memory" not removable sdcard. How did you correct the "default memory" ? also how do I know getExternalStorageDirectory() is reliable. If it cannot use, how can I locate a correct path to use ? thank you very much

Comment: @CaptainVoronin: How did you corrected default memory by coding at runtime?